# Custom StdDeserializer doesn't use the specified @JsonView

Tags: java, jackson

I use a custom deserializer, but when I call `objectMapper.writerWithView(Views.MyView.class)`, I do not get the expected result.

While debugging, I found out that in the method

```java
public MyObject deserialize(JsonParser parser, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException { 
    //do something 
}
```

the `context` variable has the field value `_view = null`. How can I have my custom Deserializer use the expected view ? The view is used for the rest of the deserialization as other objects have only the desired fields displayed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a mistake using `@JsonView` it's actually working fine, sorry I don't know how to delete my question :/

EDIT: I used `@JsonView` on top of a class that extends a generic class that contains every identification and audit fields for the database. When using `@JsonView` at the properties level instead, it would not include the inherited fields.
note : I still have to use `objectMapper.writerWithView(Views.MyView.class)` as for some reason i don't get the annotation to work on top of method call neither in my controller or my service. This isn't an issue per se, I believe it's a misunderstanding of the annotation behavior from my part.

Comment: It's better to leave your question up; this way, people with your issue can more easily see how to solve it. I recommend editing your answer with more detailed specifics on how you solved your problem, then accept your answer as soon as possible.